# Method called infinite times in Web Service

Tags: c#, service, web, wsdl, svc

For my class on Web Services I am trying to create an EXTREMELY simple login system. I ham having a problem where createAccounts() keeps getting infinite times whenever checkCredentials is called. Any idea why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class Service : IService
{
    static String path = @"PATH REMOVED";
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    StreamWriter sw = null;

    private void createAccounts()
    {
        String data = File.ReadAllText(path);
        string[] data2 = data.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < data2.Length; i++)
        {
            temp = data2[i].Split(',');
            if(!usernameExists(temp[0]) && temp[0] != "")
            {
                accounts.Add(new Account(temp[0],temp[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CreateAccount(String username, String password)
    {
        createAccounts();
        sw = File.AppendText(path);
        if (!usernameExists(username))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(username + "," + password + "\n");
            sw.Close();
            sw = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Close();
            sw = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool usernameExists(String username)
    {
        createAccounts();
        if(accounts.Exists(a => a.username == username))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public bool CheckCredentials(String username, String password)
    {
        createAccounts();
        if (usernameExists(username))
        {
            if(accounts.Find(a => a.username == username).username == username && accounts.Find(a => a.username == username).password == password)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }

}

class Account
{
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public Account(String u, String p)
    {
        username = u;
        password = p;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would help if you actually show us the code that is invoking `CheckCredentials`, since that's what you're saying gets stuck.

Comment: I am just using a console program that just tests this operation and nothing else

Comment: How exactly did you calculate that the function is called exactly `1 x infinity` and not simply a large number of times, say, pantaloonillion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop between createAccounts and usernameExists. As long as data2.Length is non-zero you'll loop endlessly.

Comment: I think you found it! Thank you!

Comment: @bam2403 - Happy to be of assistance! Please mark this as the answer if  you feel this resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

you save data in a file,you should not write it in infinite times.when you request frequently,it will write the file in muliththreading,a thread will lock the file.
i suggest you use try...catch...write the file to find problem:

```
    public bool CreateAccount(String username, String password)
    {
        createAccounts();

        try
        {
            sw = File.AppendText(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        if (!usernameExists(username))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(username + "," + password + "\n");
            sw.Close();
            sw = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Close();
            sw = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```